# How to Implement a manual carousel slider in Flutter? like swipe left or right

Tags: flutter, slider, carousel-slider

I installed [carousel_slider: ^4.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) . I am trying to implement move image with swipe only but lots of research did not get any solution.
Please help me how to implement show a slide (not auto) with sipe left or right only using carousel_slider.

no buttons required on ui.

I installed [carousel_slider: ^4.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) .

Comment: there is an option called autoplay where you can set to false

Comment: in the carousl option autoplay is already set to false, so there is no need at all, unless you have set to true then for sure the carousel will load automatically

Comment: If you want to make carousel manually, you can use PageView. it would be more dynamic and functionally reach.

Comment: @Fetex i set autoplay to false but swipe not working